# Доступ к полям главного активити

Tags: android

Есть главный класс, наследующий ActionBarActivity,
и класс, наследующий View.
Возможно ли из вью обращаться к переменным и методам главного активити?
Пока вижу две возможности: статические поля/методы активити, либо сделать класс вью вложенным.
Существует ли более толковый способ?
Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью слушателя:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyView.OnDoSomething {

  public void doSomething(){
    //do...
  }
}

public class MyView extends View {
    private OnDoSomthing mListener;
    public MyView(Context ctx){
        try {
            mListener = (OnDoSomthing)ctx;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(ctx.toString()
                    + " must implement OnDoSomthing");
        }
    }

    private void needActivityAttention(){
        if (null != mListener) {
            mListener.doSomething();
        }
    }

    public interface OnDoSomething {
        public void doSomething();
    }
}
```

Естественно можно привести ctx к вашему классу activity и обращаться к публичным методам, но кто даст гарантию, что этот view будет использоваться только в одной активити.
Корректный способ именно такой, т.е. view ничего не знает ни об имени класса activity ни о его методах и свойствах, знает лишь, что он должен реализовывать интерфейс.

Comment: Спасибо,  не все понял, но  интересно. mListener - интерфейсная ссылка на контекст. После mListener.doSomething(); она будет содержать поля, установленные в методе doSomething ?

Comment: Плохо понимаю в контексте, даже не смог привести его к классу. Попробую разобраться.

Comment: немного не так. doSomething - это метод вашей activity, который *должен* существовать, т.е. MyView требует от activity, на которой он расположен, существования метода doSomething. Этих методов может быть произвольное количество (в интерфейсе можно указать больше одного метода, разумеется), они могут возвращать произвольные данные (например, быть геттерами и сеттерами приватных свойств) и т.д.

Comment: Идеология такова, что класс MyView ничего об activity не знает кроме того/тех методов, которые описаны в интерфейсе. К классу соответственно mListener приводить не надо, работаете только с интерфейсом, вызывая методы, описанные в нем.

Comment: Прошу прощения за тупость. Строка mListener.doSomething(); приведёт к вызову одноименного метода в активити. Я правильно понял? В любом случае полезная информация, спасибо.